# Dynamic masks in CSS3 not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit

I trying to create a basic simple dynamic mask using gradient tools but it's not working correctly. **Note i'm using Google Chrome.**

If you drag the mouse from one location to another, the circle shape and blur changes which is strange.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrdSs/101/

How can I possibly fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5J8D6/4/

Don't use `circle closest-side` instead try `50px 50px`.  We needed to set an explicit shape and size

```
var t = "background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient("+e.pageX+"px "+e.pageY+"px, 50px 50px,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100px)";
```

See http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-radial-gradient-syntax/

Comment: Thank you, can I ask why 50px 50px ? what this pixel set?

Comment: The 50px 50px denotes the lengthes of the X Y axis.